# Auto complete in Sublime Text giving bizarre suggestions?

Tags: ruby, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'm sure there's a sensible explanation for this, but I get weird auto complete suggestions in sublime text 3 when coding in ruby or a ruby section in a markdown. Examples - I was hoping it would suggestion the `.capitalize` method, but instead:

**In `.md` file**:

[image]

**In `.rb` file**:

[image]

#### What I've tried

I looked in my autocomplete preferences, but I don't see anything out of place:

```
    // Enable auto complete to be triggered automatically when typing.
    "auto_complete": true,
```

#### Question

Why the autocomplete is making bizarre suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The `auto_complete` feature of sublime text 3 just scans the files inside of the folder structures and provides those "words" as autocomplete. What you are looking for is called `CodeIntel` or `intelli-sense`. Unfortunately those features are usually only available on full blown IDEs.

Sublime has some plugins which are a bit old but should still work:

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Ruby%20Completions (last update 6 years ago)
https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeCodeIntel (last update 4 years ago)

As an alternative you could use `LSP` but this requires that you have specific language servers installed:

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LSP (recent updates)